# Ant: Create directory containing file if it doesn't already exist?

Tags: ant

Basically, I get a path like "C:\test\subfolder1\subfolder2\subfolder3\myfile.txt", but it's possible that subfolders 1-3 don't exist already, which means I'd get an exception if I try to write to the file.

Is there a way to create the directory structure the target file is in, either by using some task that creates the structure when it outputs to the file and then deleting the file, or by parsing the directory part of the path and using the mkdir task first?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Ant will create the full tree of directories for you when you use the `<mkdir>` task.  So you just need to use the `<dirname>` task to get the directory name from the file name.

```
 <dirname property="directoryProperty" file="${filePathProperty}"/>
 <mkdir dir="${directoryProperty}" />
```

The first line extracts the directory portion of your file path and stores it in the `directoryProperty` property.  The second line creates the directory (and any parent directories that don't exist).

Comment: Can this work if I am looping through a task many times? directoryProperty can only be set once, right?

Comment: @yellavon if you inside of a loop you can use <var name="directoryProperty" unset="true" />

Answer (score 6):

This task works well

```
<mkdir dir="${file}/../"/>
```

Sometimes we could have an alternate choice, using touch task

```
<touch file="${file}" mkdirs="true" verbose="true"/>
```

This task should do the job but would have a side effect to create the file with zero size

Comment: @ William Leung : Welcome to SO.  Please answer new question / unwanswered questions.  This was an old one, with accepted answer. Your answer is not adding much value, IMHO.

Comment: @Jayan I disagree, it provides a different perspective and it was what I was looking for. If not for his answer, I would have needed to ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Using the

```
<mkdir dir="${dir}"/ >
```

inside your `<target>` tag should work, but I am not sure what else you want to do along with mkdir?

Comment: The problem is I don't have the directory. I have the file path. I need to get the directory from the file path or have it created.

Answer (score 4):

Just make `failonerror=false` to avoid the error to stop the whole logic.

```
<delete includeemptydirs="true" failonerror="false">
   <fileset dir="${builder-base.dir}" includes="**/*"/>
</delete>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure it'll work but you might be able to do something like the following to make the parent directory you're after:

`<mkdir dir="${file}/../"/>`

If that doesn't work straight off then it might be worth defining a property using the location syntax before creating a directory with the new property:

`<property name="dir" location="${file}/../" />`

<mkdir dir="${dir}" />

Answer (score 0):

Well-behaved Ant tasks are generally expected to create any necessary directory structures unless there is a good reason not to.

Are you writing a task? If so you should add the directory creation logic to your task. If you are getting the task from a third party you should point this fact out to them and have them fix their task. Failing that Dan's solution should work.